# Laravel: how to hide blade statements?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am setting variables `$registered` and `$paid` in blade. This results in the values being output being displayed. How do I hide the output?

**Blade:**

```
  @foreach( $user->attendees as $attendee )
          {{
            $registered = ($attendee_registered = $program->attendees->find($attendee))? $attendee_registered->pivot->registered: 0;
            $paid = ($attendee_registered = $program->attendees->find($attendee))? $attendee_registered->pivot->paid: 0;
          }}
  @endforeach
```

**HTML**

1 1 0 0 0 0 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blade is a template engine, therefore it doesn't expect you to define variables, it expects those variables to already be defined.

`{{ data }}` is equivalent to `<?php echo data ?>` in Blade 4 and `<?php echo htmlentities(data) ?>` in Blade 5.  So yes, this will not work as you expect.

You can, however, use standard PHP tags in Blade templates:

```
  @foreach( $user->attendees as $attendee )
          <?php
            $registered = ($attendee_registered = $program->attendees->find($attendee))? $attendee_registered->pivot->registered: 0;
            $paid = ($attendee_registered = $program->attendees->find($attendee))? $attendee_registered->pivot->paid: 0;
          ?>
  @endforeach
```

Comment: thanks a lot your answer helped me.I wanted to know what is the equivalent for <?php ?> in laravel 5.7 view blade or should i just keep it that way ?

Comment: Blade is compiled to php so you "can" use php tags in blade files. However, if you find yourself doing this, you're probably breaking the MVC design.

Comment: i guess so problem is i had to this because i'm migrating from laravel 4.2 to 5.7 and i don't have a lot of time.So i'll use that for now and change it correctly later

Answer (score 0):

The blade curly brackets are not for executing any old php - they are intended to be used for outputing (i.e. displaying things). You would have to surround your code in the php tags thusly:

```
@foreach( $user->attendees as $attendee )
      <?php
        $registered = ($attendee_registered = $program->attendees->find($attendee))? $attendee_registered->pivot->registered: 0;
        $paid = ($attendee_registered = $program->attendees->find($attendee))? $attendee_registered->pivot->paid: 0;
      ?>
@endforeach
```

Regardless of that it is a good practice to **do your logic inside your controllers** and not your templates, so that you reduce the dependency between your models, views and controllers. This makes views reusable and keeps everything logically separated so that you don't have to search through HTML when you want to adjust something.

Comment: I started to write a eloquent relation in the model,and the associated eloquent query in the controller to eager load it so i could do '$program->attendee->isRegistered' but I gave up... It requires a long and confusing chain of eloquent queries with callbacks...and is so hard to debug.

Comment: NWM - you probably require something more advancced